# Which websites have a ranking and/or a rating list for correspondence chess without engine help?

Tags: engines, elo, correspondence-chess

I am looking for websites that have a ranking and/or a rating list for correspondence chess without engine help. Which ones do exist?

For example, lichess.org has correspondence chess without engine help but no ranking.

I found that Lechenicher Schach Server (https://www.chess-server.net/en/)  has a new ranking for correspondence chess without engine help. Also, is 100% free.

On Lechenicher, you need to use your real name. Something that motivates to reduce cheating. On the other hand, Lichess does not require your real name. For that reason, cheaters will not have punishment because if their accounts are closed, they could return with a new name. In addition to that, it seems that Lichess does not have a cheating detection system for correspondence chess.

[image: LSS Non-engine ranking]

Comment: Correspondence without engine, is it even possible?

Comment: @SmallChess Correspondence chess started some centuries ago. No chess engines at that time existed.

Comment: OP is asking for a new rating list. Is there such a list? A list of correspondence without engine? Correspondence chess is now played with chess engines by design.

Comment: @SmallChess I agree that ICCF correspondence chess is played with chess engine help. However, there are other variations. Congratulations on your enthusiasm!